# Why do not I get results from var_dump, while doing 'console.log()' in '$http' AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, codeigniter

Here I use codeigniter and AngularJS....
What's wrong with my code?

That I want, I want to retrieve its data from 'input text'.

And I only get empty data when doing 'console.log()'

in index.html

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search_data">
<span class="display-ib" ng-click="testGetDataSearch()"></span>
```

in app.js

```
$scope.testGetDataSearch = function()
        {
          $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'home/naonwelah',
            data: { 'valSearch': $scope.search_data }
          }).then(function (success){
            console.log(success.data);
          },function (error){
            console.log(error);
          });
        }
```

in AjaxRequest.php

```
public function naonwelah()
    {
        if ( isset($_GET['valSearch'])) {
            $searchValue = $_GET['valSearch'];
            $result = $this->dbxs7h3j9213m02147ca_model->cariBrow($searchValue);
            var_dump($result);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Very Simple, Change 'data:' to 'params:', and Try This :)

```
$scope.testGetDataSearch = function()
        {
          $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'home/naonwelah',
            params: { 'valSearch': $scope.search_data }
          }).then(function (data){
            console.log(data);
          },function (error){
            console.log(error);
          });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you open the search-url directly? Do you get any output? Have you inspected the request in the ChromeDevTools? That might also help to narrow the problem down.

One issue however might be that var_dump produces no valid JSON.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but when I use $ .ajax () on jQuery I get the result as I see fit